# WPF Navigation for Wizard-Style UserControls with common Model

Tags: c#, wpf

Here's what I have

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int propertyA;
    public int PropertyA
    {
       get{ return propertyA; }
       set{ propertyA = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("PropertyA");
    }
}
```

then I have a "MainWindow" that has a set of buttons on the side for navigation, and a "main content" area to change what user control I'm using

```
<Window>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btnFirstStep" Content="firstStep" ></Button>
        <Button x:Name="btnSecondStep" Content="secondStep" ></Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="mainContent"></Grid>

</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   private Model model;
   private UserControl firstStep;
   private UserControl secondStep;
   public MainWindow()
   {
      model = new Model();
      model.PropertyChanged += PropertyChanged;
      InitializeComponent();
      firstStep = new UserControl(model);
      secondStep = new UserControl(model);
   }

   public void PropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       switch(e.PropertyName)
       {
          case "PropertyA": mainContent.content = secondStep; break;
       }
   }
```

My question is, how am I supposed to do this?  The goal is to be able to bind data to usercontrols, all coming from a common model, and navigate between different user controls, so the end result is a "Wizard" style application.

Is it ok to use a `PropertyChanged` event to change navigation, or should I be using an actual Event?

Comment: PropertyChanged  is an event....

Comment: Yes, but is that the right way to do it? Or am i breaking MVC logic in how I'm handling this.

Comment: MVC? There is no MVVM involved in your sample code if that's what you are asking.

Comment: I guess I'm asking if there's a cleaner way to do this other than the way I'm doing it

Comment: My first thought is to have VMs for each UserControl instead of using one common model. But I'm not sure if that's better or more complicated. Any hint to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an MVVM example for you. Basically you should:

- Define a command in the view model that sets a property to a type that represents the current step.
- Define a `DataTemplate` per step in the view. You could for example define a `UserControl` for each step.
- Bind the navigation button to the command

**View Model:**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel  : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel ()
    {
        NavigateCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(GoToStep);
    }

    public ICommand NavigateCommand { get; private set; }

    private IStep _currentStep;
    public IStep CurrentStep
    {
        get { return _currentStep; }
        set { _currentStep = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private void GoToStep(string s)
    {
        switch(s)
        {
            case "firstStep":
                CurrentStep = new FirstStep();
                break;
            case "secondStep":
                CurrentStep = new SecondStep();
                break;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public interface IStep { }

public class FirstStep : IStep { }

public class SecondStep : IStep { }
```

**View:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btnFirstStep" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="firstStep" Content="firstStep"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnSecondStep" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="secondStep" Content="secondStep"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentStep}" Grid.Column="1">
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FirstStep}">
                <TextBlock>first...</TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SecondStep}">
                <TextBlock>second...</TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Resources>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

---

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: this was EXTREMELY helpful. Thank you!